# How to get a specific object from an array field with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, lodash

Given a schema like this:

```
UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  donations: [
    {
      amount: Number,
      charity: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'charity'
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

I have the (string) ids of a user and of a nonprofit and I want to get the amount the user donated. Im using this query with lodash:

```
User.findOne({
  _id: userId
}, function(err, user) {
  var amount = _.find(user.donations, {charity: charityId});
  console.log("the amount is: ", amount);
});
```

Here the amount returns undefined even though it shouldn't also im guessing i shouldn't have to use `lodash`. What's the right way to get to the amount donated given a specific `userId` and `charityId`?

Comment: not really because I am filtering after selecting and it doesnt work probably because charity is an Object and im searching on a string id

Comment: OK, I'm a bit unsure what you're trying to do because you're passing `user.shares` to `_.find` but `shares` doesn't appear in your schema.  Should that be `user.donations`?

Comment: So how does the referenced question not help you? The point there is that you can process this in the MongoDB server rather than filter in your node client code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pretty similar to the possible duplicate I linked to, as you can do this without using lodash as:

```
User.findOne({
  _id: userId,
  'donations.charity': charityId
}, {
  'donations.$': 1
}, function(err, user) {
  console.log("the amount is: ", user.donations[0].amount);
});
```

Comment: is the [0] in this --> console.log("the amount is: ", user.donations[0].amount); correct because of 'donations.$':1?

Comment: @user3854950 Right, the [`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) limits that array field to contain just the first matching element.

Comment: This is great! Worked out fine thanks :)